# How to use Google Talk voice and video calling on an Android?

Tags: video, google-talk, video-conference

How do you do Google talk voice and video calling from android.

The google talk application only appears to allow text based chatting. But Google talk on the desktop supports both voice calling and video chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>There is no official Google talk voice/video chat for Android phones.</strike> You can use Google Talk in Android 2.3.4+ to make video chats now. Additionally, any calls made via Google Voice are done via cell tower (using your minutes), not data.

Comment: That last part is not necessarily true. There is a workaround to make VOIP calls over Cell or WiFi. http://lifehacker.com/5354607/make-and-receive-free-phone-calls-with-google-voice-and-android

Comment: @Webs I meant natively with the official app.  There are always workarounds :)

Comment: No worries Bryan, I figured as much.

Comment: Google voice is not available in my country New Zealand or in most other parts of the world.

Comment: this is not what the OP asked though, he's asking about Google Talk, not Google Voice.

Comment: @BryanDenny The Answer to this question is not up to date. Please update your answer.

Comment: @flow Fixed post

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to bump an old question, but you can now make both audio and video calls from android with google talk if you have 2.3.4 (gingerbread) or higher.
[1](http://www.gsmarena.com/google_talk_update_brings_video_chat_to_your_android_device-news-2577.php)